# Unable to Sort data in dual foreach loop in Laravel

Tags: laravel, foreach, eloquent, laravel-blade, laravel-query-builder

I am fetching data of `User` with the `Subject` model and `Review` model. There is a rating column in the `Review` of the related `User`. What I am trying to do is fetch the highest rating first but failed.

Heres my Controller:

```
function guest()
{
    $topTutors = User::where('type', 'tutor')->with('subject')->with('review')->get();     

    return view('welcome', compact('topTutors'));
}
```

```
@foreach($topTutor->review as $singleReview)
    <div class="star-rating" data-rating="{{ $singleReview->rating }}"></div>
@endforeach
```

Here's the Blade where I wasn't able to sort Data I used sortbyDesc but It's not working:

Comment: Please can you show how you used `sortByDesc()`.

Comment: <div class="freelancer-rating">
                                        @foreach($topTutor->review->sortByDesc('rating') as $singleReview)
                                            @dump($singleReview)
                                        @endforeach
                                    </div>

Here's the code
The but there's no effect on output!
Check out the screenshot:
https://photos.app.goo.gl/5etyyQqHcqoKAWqVA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this to sort your users based on their review rating:

```php
$topTutors = User::where('type', 'tutor')
    ->with('subject', 'review')
    ->get()
    ->sortbyDesc(function($user) {
        return $user->review->max('rating');
    });
```

Comment: It's still the same!
Please check out the screenshot.
https://photos.app.goo.gl/SFerAecUmHX222CW6

Comment: @ショーアイブ oh you're trying to sort your users based on their review rating, check my updated answer.

Comment: Ahhhh it's still same!! :l
Please check out my blade Code
https://docs.google.com/document/d/1I5QpTdtia6mY-rJyeiHlklCRzQAuppuLms99poK6LKg/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: @ショーアイブ provided link is not accessible.

Comment: Please check out now:
https://docs.google.com/document/d/1aX-tekoM2nAztWSIL7PmDanLAom1smuNtC_KVA0n7hs/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: @ショーアイブ the `user->review` relation is one-to-one or one-to-many or what? would you plz post related parts of `user` model?

Comment: In the User Model:
public function review()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Review','reviewed_id');
    }


In the Review Model:
public function user()
    {

        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\User');
    }